# How to rewrite code so method doesn't require parameter?

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent

Currently having the problem of trying to call display() for the paint method of ball class, but it won't let me call it without giving a parameter such as Graphics2D g. Any suggestions?

```
public class Main extends JPanel {


Ball b;
Graphics2D graph;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    int xRange = 1000;
    int yRange = 1000;

    //creates window
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Tahmaseeb");
    Ball b = new Ball();

    f.setSize(1000,1000);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while(true){
        b.move();
        b.display();
    }
} }
```

OTHER BALL CLASS

```
    /**
 * Painting the object
 */

void display(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillOval(this.posX, this.posY, 20, 20);

}
```

Comment: Start by reading [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to gain a better understanding of how painting actually works in Swing and how you're suppose to integrate with it

Comment: Then, read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to get a better understanding of why you're current approach is dangerous and unrecommended then read [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a place to start for solving that problem

Comment: Yours is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)